# Getting a method or data member not found in a class module

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the code for the class module (where it errors on the code module):

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
    Dim VBAEditor As VBIDE.VBE
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim mdl As Object
    Dim mdl_exits As Boolean
    Dim mdl_name As String
    Dim macro_name As String
    Dim macro_exists As Boolean

    mdl_name = "SaveButtons"
    For Each mdl In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        If mdl.Name = mdl_name And mdl.Type = 1 Then
            Set prrf_Module = mdl
            mdl_exists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If mdl_exists Then GoTo it_exists

    Set prrf_Module = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
    prrf_Module.Name = mdl_name

it_exists:
    macro_exists = False
    macro_name = SaveButton.Value

new_name:
    If macro_exists = True Then
        If macro_name = SaveButton.Value Then
            macro_name = SaveButton.Value & "1"
        Else
            macro_name = Left(macro_name, Len(macro_name) - 1) & CInt(Mid(macro_name, Len(macro_name) - 1)) + 1
        End If
    End If
    macro_exists = False

    zy = "Userform1.show"

    strMacro = "Sub " & "CommandButton1" & vbCr
    strMacro = strMacro & "    " & zy & vbCr
    strMacro = strMacro & "End Sub" & vbCr

    Debug.Print "strMacro is " & vbCr & strMacro

    'Set prrf_Module = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
    Dim d, e, f, y
    For y = 1 To 2
        With btn_Gen.CodeModule
            d = .CountOfLines
            .insertlines 1, "Sub CommandButton" & y & "_Click()"
            For e = LBound(t) To UBound(t)
                countlines = countlines + 1
                upper = UBound(t)
                xy = countlines + 1
                .insertlines xy, "    " & t(e)
            Next e
            .insertlines xy + 1, "End Sub"
        End With
    Next y

End Sub
```

And here is my module code (that runs till I click commandbutton1)

```
Sub showuserform1()

    Dim x, y
    Dim z() As String

    Set btn_nm = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set lbl_tx = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set code = New Scripting.Dictionary

    repeatx:
    x = UCase(InputBox("(H)orizontal or (V)ertical?", "Orientation", "H"))
    If x = "H" Then
        orientation = "Horizontal"
    ElseIf x = "V" Then
        orientation = "Vertical"
    Else
        MsgBox ("Input either 'H' or 'V'")
        GoTo repeatx
    End If
    repeatcount:
    count = InputBox("How many buttons do you want? ", "Button Count", "1")
    If count < 1 Then
        MsgBox ("Input Quantity of Buttons, enter at least 1")
        GoTo repeatcount:
    End If

    For y = 1 To count
        btn_nm(y) = InputBox("What do you want CommandButton" & y + 1 & " to say?", "CommandButton name", "CommandButton" & y)
        lbl_tx(y) = InputBox("What do you want Label" & y + 1 & " to say?", "Label text", "Label" & y)
        btn_Gen_uf2.Label1.Caption = "Enter Code in Window - max 8k characters"
        btn_Gen_uf2.TextBox1.Value = ""
    repeatshow:
        btn_Gen_uf2.TextBox1.SetFocus
        btn_Gen_uf2.Show
        If btn_Gen_uf2.TextBox1.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Enter Code in Window before selecting OK"
            GoTo repeatshow:
        End If

        t = Split(btn_Gen_uf2.TextBox1.Text, vbCrLf)

        ReDim z(0 To UBound(t), 1 To count)
        For w = LBound(t) To UBound(t)
            MsgBox t(w)
            'Debug.Print "z(" & w & "," & y & ") = " & t(w)
            z(w, y) = t(w)
        Next w
    Next y

    ' Do this last
    btn_Gen.Show
End Sub
```

This is crossposted from [excelforum](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1268868-how-to-optimize-button-generator-code-2.html).

I added the declarations (see above) and now am getting an error on this line: Dim VBAEditor as VBIDE.VBE

The error is *"User-defined type not defined"*. Am I missing a reference?

Comment: the `Codemodule` property only applies to the `CodePane` and `VBComponent` objects.

Comment: see modified code above, why am i getting this error?

Comment: Have you ticked the box to 'Trust access to the VBA project object model'? I suspect that it is relevant.

Comment: You need a reference to the `Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility` library.

Comment: yah,  took a minute to find the reference but now that i am past that, still getting: Method or data member not found on this line: With btn_Gen.CodeModule. is there a declaration missing?

Comment: Like I said, the `Codemodule` property only applies to two objects, neither of which is `Userform`.

Comment: ok, that helps. gonna post back to excelforum as i got it to create module and code (but the code is whacked so just have to figure that out and then this will work). ok to close this as solved

Answer (score 0):

With rory's help, I made this one change and most of the code is working.

```
With Prrf_Module.CodeModule
```

instead of

```
With btn_Gen.Codemodule
```